Azure Data Factory (ADF) dataflow shows date values as Null
I created a dataset from a csv in a datalake storage.
When I preview the data, via the dataset, every column shows correctly.

When I use the same dataset in a source transformation of a dataflow it shows the date columns as null

This happens despite that the projection tab of the dataflow manages to detect correctly the data types when I press the detect data type button

Any ideas why this might happen?

For some reason I had to specify the format in the Projection tab.

Then, when I previewed the data, it looked as expected:

